# How to run SimpleSwingApplication from console main method?

Tags: swing, scala, console

I wrote my first console app in Scala, and I wrote my first Swing app in Scala -- in case of the latter, the entry point is **top** method in my object extending **SimpleSwingApplication**.

However I would like to still go through **main** method, and from there call **top** -- or perform other equivalent actions (like creating a window and "running" it).

How to do it?

*Just in case if you are curious why, the GUI is optional, so I would like to parse the command line arguments and then decide to show (or not) the app window.*

Comment: If you use IntelliJ or similar, it's easy to Ctrl-click through to see the source of SimpleSwingApplication, which will help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have something like:

```
object MySimpleApp extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  // ...
}
```

You can just call `MySimpleApp.main` to start it from the console. A `main` method is added when you mix `SimpleSwingApplication` trait. Have a look at the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.swing.SimpleSwingApplication).

Comment: I meant from the "traditional" main method, so the user won't spot the difference. With information from you, it was piece of cake, I simply called GUI main from the "traditional" main. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks.  I was struggling with googling all over the place and could not figure out how to run the Artima Odersky book's GUI example (FirstSwingApp).  Now I just put in my main object a line FirstSwingApp.main(args) and works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the most basic example:

```
import swing._

object MainApplication {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    GUI.main(args)
 }

  object GUI extends SimpleSwingApplication {
    def top = new MainFrame {
      title = "Hello, World!"
    }
  }
}
```

Execute `scala MainApplication.scala` from the command line to start the Swing application.

Comment: How would i return a value from the GUI application back to my MainApplication?

Comment: You could write a method that wraps GUI.main and returns a value

Answer (score 2):

If you override the main method that you inherit from SimpleSwingApplication, you can do whatever you want:

```
object ApplicationWithOptionalGUI extends SimpleSwingApplication {

  override def main(args: Array[String]) =
    if (parseCommandLine(args))
      super.main(args) // Starts GUI
    else
      runWithoutGUI(args)

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed main.args to be usable in SimpleSwingApplication. I wanted to give a filename to process as an argument in CLI, or then use JFileChooser in case the command line argument list was empty.

**I do not know if there is simple method to use command line args in SimpleSwingApplication**, but how I got it working was to define, in demoapp.class:

```
class demoSSA(args: Array[String]) extends SimpleSwingApplication {
    ....
    var filename: String = null
    if (args.length > 0) {
        filename = args(0)
    } else {
        // use JFileChooser to select filename to be processed 
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627894/scala-class-running-a-file-chooser
    }
    ....
}

object demo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val demo = new demoSSA(args)
     demo.startup(args)
  }
}
```

Then start the app by 
*demo [args]*, by giving filename as a CLI argument or leaving it empty and program uses JFileChooser to ask it.

**Is there a way to get to the args of main() in SimpleSwingApplication singleton object?**
Because it doesn't work to parse 'filename' in overridden SimpleSwingApplication.main and to use 'filename' in the singleton object it needs to be declared (val args: Array[String] = null;), not just defined (val args: Array[String];). And singleton objecs inherited from SSA cannot have parameters.

(Edit)
Found one another way:
If whole demoSSA is put inside overridden main() or startup(), then top MainFrame needs to defined outside as top = null and re-declare it from startup() as this.top:

```
object demo extends SimpleSwingApplication {  
  var top: MainFrame = null
  override def startup(args: Array[String]) {
    ...  // can use args here
    this.top = new MainFrame {
      ... // can use args here also
    };
    val t = this.top
    if (t.size == new Dimension(0,0)) t.pack()
      t.visible = true
  }
}
```

But I think I like the former method more, with separated main object.It has at least one level indentation less than the latter method.